# GitHub repo grey folder

Tags: github

I am trying to push to my remote repository on GitHub using EGit for Eclipse. But I get a greyed out folder instead.

Why is it greyed out? 
Is this because I haven't configured EGit correctly? I am trying to push a new project onto an existing repository with several folders in it. I cloned the repository by importing it. And I `Shared` the new project with the existing repository.

However, when I edit the source file and try to commit the change, it shows no changes have been made.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), i.e. a way to reference another git repository in a directory.

The contents of the directory (when fully checked out) is contained another git repository completely different from the one you have currently open. As the other repository can be anywhere, Github isn't able to display its contents there.

You should see a `.gitmodules` File in the root of your directory that contains the references. Have a look there and refer to the other repository directly.

Comment: I don't see the `.gitmodules` folder. This is frustrating so right now, I'm just cloning the repository to a folder on my desktop and then using Git from my terminal instead of Eclipse.

Comment: It's not a folder but a file (which might appear hidden locally).

Comment: Oh right, that's what I meant. I don't see the file, even with `View Hidden Files` option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `Assinment_6_Program_1` directory is already a git init directory, which means it already has a hidden directory `.git` in it.

`.git` is a directory saves all git config files.

It becomes gray because `Assinment_6_Program_1`'s parent directory is already a git project. So it would become normal when you delete `.git` and push your directory again.